# How do I make use of I/O threads?

Tags: quarkus

According to article: https://quarkus.io/blog/resteasy-reactive-smart-dispatch/ I should be able to use I/O threads by "just" annotating methods with `@NonBlocking`.

When using the latest quarkus quickstarts, and modifying the getting-started example:

```java
@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

    @Inject
    GreetingService service;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/greeting/{name}")
    @Blocking
    public String greeting(@PathParam String name) {
        System.out.println( "greeting, isWorker: " + ( (io.vertx.core.impl.VertxThread)Thread.currentThread() ).isWorker() );
        return service.greeting(name);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @NonBlocking
    public String hello() {
        System.out.println( "hello, isWorker: " + ( (io.vertx.core.impl.VertxThread)Thread.currentThread() ).isWorker() );
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

I would expect to get an I/O thread for the `hello` method. However, this is the result:

```
2021-12-28 14:07:17,990 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) getting-started 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 2.6.1.Final) started in 0.543s. Listening on: http://localhost:8080
2021-12-28 14:07:17,990 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated.
2021-12-28 14:07:17,991 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Installed features: [cdi, resteasy, smallrye-context-propagation, vertx]
2021-12-28 14:07:17,991 INFO  [io.qua.dep.dev.RuntimeUpdatesProcessor] (vert.x-worker-thread-0) Live reload total time: 0.676s 
hello, isWorker: true
greeting, isWorker: true
```

So in both cases (according to the vert.x-worker-thread) a worker and not I/O thread.

Quarkus version is 2.6.1Final

What do I miss?

Comment: ah.. apparently its a dependency that needs to be changed.. continue to check

Answer (score 1):

Checking if the current thread is of type `io.vertx.core.impl.VertxThread` is not the way to check you are on the event-loop, as the same type of thread can be used for the worker pool as well.

The proper way to do this check in Quarkus is to use:

```
var onEventLoop = !io.quarkus.runtime.BlockingOperationControl.isBlockingAllowed()
```

Comment: I replaced dependency: <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId> and got the results I expected with the example above. Is that dependency required? I'll try yours as well.

Comment: also: from the looks of it, isBlockingAllowed seems to express more a capability. Right? Not the type of thread I'm actually dealing with..

Comment: Yes, it's the actual test of whether or not you are on the event loop